# Score calculator

Tags: java

Ok, so, I am very new to java.
I am designing a score calculator, for a project that I have long left aside. Still, I would like to know how to do this, for my own knowledge.

The program is supposed to ask for a dice roll, and add it to the previous rolls, for each player.
I assumed a while loop would accomplish this, but every time it goes through the loop it resets the variable to the current roll. As such, I cannot get a total...

Below is some code:

```
    static int players;
    static String p1;
    static String p2;
    static String p3;
    static String p4;
    static int maxScore;
    static int roll1;
    static int roll2;
    static int roll3;
    static int roll4;
    static int total1;
    static int total2;
    static int total3;
    static int total4;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of players: ");
    players=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Maximum Score: ");
    maxScore=keyboard.nextInt();
    if(players==2){                    //will add more ifs when i get the code right
        System.out.println("Please enter players names.");
        System.out.print("Player 1: ");
        p1=keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("Player 2: ");
        p2=keyboard.next();
        System.out.println(p1 + "\t \t " + p2 + "\n"
        + "_______ \t _______ \n" );  //displays scorecard look with players names

        {


        while (total1 < maxScore && total2<maxScore) { 
        //scorecard quits when maxScore is reached by either player
        int roll;
        total1=(roll+roll1); 

        System.out.print("");
        roll=keyboard.nextInt(); //asks for current roll

        System.out.print("\n"+"_____"+"\n");
        System.out.print(roll+"+"+"\n"+roll1+"\n"+"_____"+"\n"+(roll+roll1)+"\n");
        /*i want this to display total score + last roll and then 
        *total it again on the next line*/
        roll1=roll;
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you're assigning `roll1` to `roll` instead of adding its value. You might try: `roll1+=roll;`

Comment: whats with the opening brace before the while loop? What variable is supposed to hold the total? is it total1? if so, just load the roll into roll1 and then do total += roll1 (+= means total = total + roll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints for your programming progress in Java:

1. The variable `roll` serves no purpose. `roll1`, and so on, will store the last roll for each player.
2. Initialize your variables, if possible. Relying on default values should be avoided, as it may bring you problems as you learn (`NullPointerException` will pay you a visit sometime).
3. In your loop, you had `total1=(roll+roll1);`. This is wrong. Your variables, `total1`, `roll`, `roll1` are not initialized by the time the program reaches this point. As they are integers, they are (silently) initialized to 0, so `total1` yields 0 at this point, which does not accomplish much. After this, you proceed to retrieve the roll. Try the other way around, first the roll, then adding up.
4. You mentioned you're new to Java, but, at some point in the future, you might consider implementing this same program with arrays. You'll notice it saves you much of the repeating code you wrote now.

Summing up, and translating to code guidelines (for 2 players):

```
public class MyScoreCalculator {
    static String p1 = "";
    static String p2 = "";
    static int maxScore = 0;
    static int roll1 = 0;
    static int roll2 = 0;
    static int total1 = 0;
    static int total2 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Dialogue to get data...
        // Display scorecard look with players names

        while (total1 < maxScore && total2 < maxScore) { 
            //scorecard quits when maxScore is reached by either player
            roll1 = keyboard.nextInt(); // ask for current roll

            System.out.println(total1 + "+");
            System.out.println(roll1);
            System.out.println("_____");
            System.out.println(roll1 + total1);

            total1 = total1 + roll1;

            // Do the same for next player.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally realized I defined total too early in the loop. And I know I have a lot to learn. This is my first programming language and I've only been at it for a week. Thank you for the help though

Comment: @derek Slow and steady, that's how everyone goes when learning programming. There's nothing wrong with that. That 4th hint I pointed out will surely show up sooner or later, in your learning path, as well as the suggestion given by Charles, in his answer, although that is a bit more advanced stuff, for a beginner. If any of these answers solves your problem, do not forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly then the solution is

```
total1+=(roll+roll1);
```

which is the same thing as

```
total1= total1+(roll+roll1);
```

Your just not adding the rolls to the total value!

Also as a point of note, it is not a good idea to have your instance variables as public and static. It would be better if they were private and not static. For example

```
    private int players;
```

Hope the answer helps

Comment: thank you for the response. in my original code i did have the total adding to the next roll. i must have somehow left that out. the problem i am having is that when it goes to display the total it displays a '0'

Answer (score 0):

Your total1 calculation should be `total1 += roll` and happen after the new roll input. Also if roll1 represents the last roll, name the variable accordingly, it's much more readable.

Since you have many players, try to abstract the concepts and separate the input from the "accounting". For example, you could create a PlayerScore class that holds a total and the last input (and the player's name), with a method that takes care of adding and saving the last input, as well as prettyprinting the infos. You can then have a collection of PlayerScore and iterate over it, ask the current roll and have the infos updated.